# Simple SlickGrid's Data not displaying

Tags: slickgrid

Just started using SlickGrid, Not sure if I am missing something, but this simple code doesn't seem to work. It is displaying headers, but not the rows.

**Grid Code:**

```
var grid;
var data = [
   { ID: 1, VALUE: "Value1"},
   { ID: 2, VALUE: "Value2"},
   { ID: 3, VALUE: "Value3"},
   { ID: 4, VALUE: "Value4"},
   { ID: 5, VALUE: "Value5"}
];
var columns = [
   {name:'ID NUM', field:'ID', id:'ID'},
   {name:'VALUE', field:'VALUE', id:'VALUE'}    
];
var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
};
grid = new Slick.Grid("#container-div", data, columns, options);
grid.render();
```

For some reason, only first row's first cell is rendered in html and is not been displayed.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slick-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; outline: 0px none; position: relative; height: 0px;">
   <div class="grid-canvas" style="height: 150px; width: 880px;">
      <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px">
        <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">1</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the container div to display the data, in your javascript code you are referencing `#container-div` but it does not exist inside your html code. Typically you don't have to write any html code like you seem to be doing (or is it the result you displayed?), except for the grid container itself. Try simply adding or replacing with this code in your html body: `<div id="container-div" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>` You can see a simple example from SlickGrid here: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example1-simple.html